# PHP doesn't get the id attribute variable from JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

Okay so I have a mysql table (with id, name, photo, etc.) that shows an image for each id. When I click on each image, it opens a modal, which I want to display the name from the given id.

```
<input type="image" src="imatges/<?php echo $row['foto']; ?>" id="<?php echo $row['id']?>" class="img-rounded image" width="250px" height="200px" data-target="#myModal"/>
```

The problem is that I try to get the image id using Jquery then pass it to php so that it can show the name on the modal, but it doesn't work. It says "no" instead. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

```
<!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="btn close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>

                        <?php
                        $id = isset($_POST['id']);
                        if(!$id){
                            echo "no";
                        }

                        $prepIexec2 = $conn->prepare('SELECT nom FROM TaulaGats WHERE id = :id');
                        $prepIexec2->bindParam(':id', $id);
                        $prepIexec2->execute();

                        while($row = $prepIexec2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                            extract($row);
                        ?>

                        <h4 class="h4"><span></span><?php echo $row; } ?></h4>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $(".image").click(function(){
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: { id: id },
                        success: function (result) {
                            $("#myModal").modal();
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

Comment: You're never doing anything with `result`.

Comment: The modal just contains whatever it had when you first loaded the page, you're never updating it with the AJAX response.

Comment: You also need to do `$id = $_POST['id'];`

Comment: Okay I tried writing $id = $_POST['id']; but it doesn't work either. What should I do with result? I mean all I wanna do is get the id attribute with PHP. :/

Comment: `echo $row` makes no sense. `$row` is an array, you can't echo it.

Comment: Here: `data: { id: id },`. I think that should be `data: { "id": id },`

Comment: I think you need to read a tutorial on AJAX. The AJAX script doesn't update the browser by itself. The AJAX script should return data or HTML, and then the Javascript uses this to update the DOM to display the returned information.

Comment: @Zeke There's no difference between those. You don't have to quote keys in object literals, unless they contain special characters.

Comment: A modal's HTML would typically be served as part of the original document. You would typically make an AJAX request only to obtain data from the server.

Comment: @Barmar I don't particularly like jQuery so I don't use it, but wouldn't that be treated as a variable? It wouldn't work. If `isset()` says false, then for some reason AJAX isn't sending the data to the server. It must be a jQuery issue.

Comment: @Zeke No, the keys of object literals are not treated as variables, only the values are.

Comment: @Zeke This is basic Javascript syntax, nothing to do with jQuery. Type `{foo: "bar"}` into the Javascript console.

Comment: @Barmar You're right, I'm well aware about that syntax, I was just guessing that the server isn't receiving the data because Evan says the output is 'no' and since the append method minds about data types I just went with it and forgot this is not a method.

Comment: @Zeke The "no" output is coming from when he first loads the page, because he never does anything with the result of the AJAX call. There's no `$_POST` data when the page is first loaded, so of course it says `no`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I got that later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery code needs to update the DOM using the information returned from the PHP script.

You should have a script that just returns the name you want to look up, without all the HTML surrounding it.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['id'])) {
    echo "no";
    exit;
}
$id = $_POST['id'];
require_once("dbsetup.php"); // or whatever you use to initialize your database connection
$prepIexec2 = $conn->prepare('SELECT nom FROM TaulaGats WHERE id = :id');
$prepIexec2->bindParam(':id', $id);
$prepIexec2->execute();
$row = $prepIexec2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($row) {
    echo $row['nom'];
} else {
    echo "no";
}
```

Then your Javascript would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".image").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: "getNom.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { id: id },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#myModal h4 span").text(result);
                $("#myModal").modal();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work either! gives me the same error. Man this is driving me nuts, am I that dumb? Your answer looks so good I don't get why it's still not working :(

Comment: Oops, I left out the `$id` assignment.

Comment: Yes. Don't you have enough rep to make trivial edits like that? I don't mind typo fixes.